# Move in a serpentine line or snake line

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

A car should go from A to B. But not in the direct line. As in reality, it should drive in 2 arcs as shown in the diagram. Is there some kind of function for this? How would it be used?

[image]

Comment: what are u trying to achieve here? also what have u tried so far

Comment: you may be looking for [control theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this as an `ellipse` and `calculate the perimeter of ellipse` by giving length and magnitude, you can get your path length

```
import math
def calculate_perimeter(a,b):
    perimeter = math.pi * ( 3*(a+b) - math.sqrt( (3*a + b) * (a + 3*b) ) )
    return perimeter

calculate_perimeter(distance/2, magnitude_of_deviation/2)
```

Edit

```
distance = absolute(p1-p2)   
         =  math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
```

you have start p1(x,y) and p2 (x2,y2), absolute distance is distance at here and deviation magnitude is your choice and one eclipse would work for all distance

Comment: Taking an Elippse is a good idea. I then pack 2 elips in a row and then drive the dotted line with the car. so i get 
Which formula do I use to determine the coordinates x, y of the points on the ellipse circumference

Comment: please structure your question, you have start p1(x,y) and p2 (x2,y2), absolute distance is distance at here and deviation magnitude is your choice and one eclipse would work for all distance